# Unity new input system returning 0 or not working

Tags: unity-game-engine, input

I am trying to use Unity's new input system to simply read the mouse position. I created a `StandardMap` InputActionMap asset, with a `CursorPosition` InputAction configured to read the mouse position ("Value & Vector2" action).

I should be able to read the value of the mouse using something like:

```
Vector2 pointerPosition = 
 theInputMapAsset.FindActionMap("StandardMap").FindAction("CursorMovement").ReadValue<Vector2>();
```

Unfortunately, `pointerPosition` always returns 0,0! I tried everything and it doesn't seem to work...

**EDIT:** This situation happens, it turns out, if you have no `PlayerInput` component that defines a default input handler as noted in: https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/manual/Components.html
The answer below does still apply, as it correctly warns that an input map must be explicitly enabled if there is no player input component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you need to `Enable()` the `InputActionMap` before using it! Calling the following code enabled the input correctly:

```
theInputMapAsset.FindActionMap("StandardMap").Enable()
```

*(of course you should probably save references to the action map/actions instead of calling `FindActionMap` every frame)*